# The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load: cdrom

Tags: windows-7, drivers, compact-disc

I am getting the error message from the title:

```
The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load:  cdrom
```

in event viewer during startup, and as a consequence Windows 7 doesn't recognize my cdrom. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314060.

Microsoft says that for Windows 7 that [the Hardware and Devices troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Open-the-Hardware-and-Devices-troubleshooter) will fix it, but you might try the Win-XP steps (they worked for me):

1. Start ***regedit***.
2. Navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
   ```
3. Delete any `UpperFilters` keys.
   Note:  If the failure occurred after installing (or attempting to) some malware like *iTunes*, *AnyDVD*, etc.;  editing the key to just remove the corresponding entry (if you can tell which it is) may save you from having to reinstall your other software that makes heavy use of the drive.

   The entry for *iTunes* is typically `GEARAspiWDM`.

   Sometimes you can see the last good values at:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Class\{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
   ```

   or later.
4. Delete any `LowerFilters` keys.  The note, from step 3, about last good entries, applies.
5. Restart the computer.
6. You *may* need to reinstall programs like *iTunes*, *Nero*, *Roxio Creator*, *DVDFab*, etc., to get them to use the drive again.

---

Note these steps also work for the Event log entry:

> The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load:  Imapi